# user-defined type not defined in vb6 While I didn't make any new type

Tags: vb6

`Function mot(ch As String, c As Char, i As Integer) As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    j = InStr(ch, 1, c)
    If j = -1 Then
        mot = j
    ElseIf j = i Then
        mot = 0
    Else
        For k = j To Len(ch) - 1
            If Mid(ch, k, 1) = c Then
                a = a + 1
            End If
        Next
        mot = a
    End If
End Function`

Highligh: First line (function mot ...)
Error: user-defined type not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you shure, you are talking about VB6? I don´t remember a datatype "CHAR" in VB6. Try string type.